# Не работает скрипт скрыть/показать блок по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо по клику на кнопку скрыть/показать блок. Использую методы slideUp и slideDown.

Не работает, ошибка `hiddenBlock.slideDown is not a function`

Вот код

```
<label class="param">CVV2/CVC2 </label>
<span id="about" class="about-button"></span>
<div id="showDiv" class="hidden-block"> 
<div class="title-h1">CVV2/CVC2</div>    
<div class="hide-div-text">
<p>Наибольшее и наименьшее значения функции, исключая очевидный случай, создает невероятный интеграл по поверхности. Ввиду непрерывности функции f ( x ), расходящийся ряд независим. Интеграл по бесконечной области, следовательно, упорядочивает равновероятный интеграл от функции, обращающейся в бесконечность вдоль линии. Линейное уравнение расточительно порождает вектор, таким образом сбылась мечта идиота - утверждение полностью доказано. Арифметическая прогрессия синхронизирует невероятный интеграл Фурье, откуда следует доказываемое равенство.</p></div>
```

```
.about-button{
    background: #000;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.hidden-block{
    display:none;
    margin-top:30px;
    position:relative;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}


var showDivButton = document.getElementById('about'),   
hiddenBlock = document.getElementById('showDiv');
var is_open = false;
showDivButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var duration = 1 * 1000;
    if(is_open) {
        return hiddenBlock.slideUp(duration);
    } else {
        return hiddenBlock.slideDown(duration);
    }
});
```

Полный код [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/9sL72gzn/)

Comment: а с чего вы взяли что у html элементов есть функции `slideUp`, `slideDown`? и в чем смысл: `1 * 1000`?

Comment: это скорость открытия блока

Comment: 1 * 1000 = 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы опять перепутали где вы хотите без jQuery, а где с ним. В данном случае: `slideUp` и `slideDown` -  методы jQuery, но вы их вызываете у нативного html объекта.

Для решения, замените

```
hiddenBlock = document.getElementById('showDiv');
```

на

```
hiddenBlock = $('#showDiv');
```

Кроме того, не меняется переменная `is_open`, так как она всегда `false` элемент один раз откроется и больше не закроется по повторному клику.

Пример

```js
var showDivButton = document.getElementById('about'),

  hiddenBlock = $('#showDiv');


var is_open = false;
showDivButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var duration = 1 * 1000;
  if (is_open) {
    is_open = false;
    return hiddenBlock.slideUp(duration);
  } else {
    is_open = true;
    return hiddenBlock.slideDown(duration);
  }
});
```

```css
 .about-button {
   background: #000;
   width: 18px;
   height: 18px;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 0 5px 0;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
 .hidden-block {
   display: none;
   margin-top: 30px;
   position: relative;
   background: #fff;
   z-index: 2;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="param">CVV2/CVC2</label>
<span id="about" class="about-button"></span>



<div id="showDiv" class="hidden-block">

  <div class="title-h1">CVV2/CVC2</div>

  <div class="hide-div-text">
    <p>
      Наибольшее и наименьшее значения функции, исключая очевидный случай, создает невероятный интеграл по поверхности. Ввиду непрерывности функции f ( x ), расходящийся ряд независим. Интеграл по бесконечной области, следовательно, упорядочивает равновероятный
      интеграл от функции, обращающейся в бесконечность вдоль линии. Линейное уравнение расточительно порождает вектор, таким образом сбылась мечта идиота - утверждение полностью доказано. Арифметическая прогрессия синхронизирует невероятный интеграл
      Фурье, откуда следует доказываемое равенство.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35231/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy--------).